# WireMock fail after half of the body has been sent

Tags: c#, .net, wiremock

We want to simulate in a test that sending the response fails after half of the body has already been sent to the client.

The best we could come up with has been:

```
_server.Given(Request.Create().UsingGet())
  .RespondWith(Response.Create().WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK).WithBody(rm => throw new Exception()));
```

However, this already returns InternalServerError instead of OK to the client. That's not what we want.

How to properly return OK and then fail after a few bytes of the body have been sent?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no way to do that, but we can use "Faults" as described in https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/wiki/Faults

We're going to use:

```
_server.Given(Request.Create().UsingGet())
  .RespondWith(Response.Create()
    .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    .WithBody(someBody)
    .WithFaults(FaultType.MALFORMED_RESPONSE_CHUNK, 0.5));
```